# How do i rewrite my code with Routers? Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, code-inspection

I have this REST API:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list', 
                                        'post': 'create', 
                                        'delete': 'delete'})),
    path('users/<uuid:pk>/video/', UserViewSet.as_view({'post': 'video'}))
]
```

How can i rewrite this with routers?

Default router with register method creates API -> `GET users/` and `POST users/` and also `DELETE /users/{id}` but it's different from current, because i need `DELETE /users/` endpoint.

Or, maybe, in this situation it would be more correct to use my code with dictionaries?

Comment: See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#example

Comment: @RossRogers there's examples for a classical REST API, not for custom. The problem is `DELETE users/` request, router creates `DELETE users/{id} `

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `UserViewSet` is indeed a viewset, you can use the restframework's default router to register the router for `/users/`, and then add an action to handle you `/video/` route from that viewset.

*urls.py*

```py
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users/', UserViewSet, basename='users')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

*viewsets.py*

```py
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet
from rest_framework.mixins import (
    CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, 
    DestroyModelMixin, ListModelMixin
)
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser

class UserViewSet(CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, 
                  DestroyModelMixin, ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    # serializer class
    # queryset
    # permissions

    @action(methods=['post'], parser_classes=(MultiPartParser,), detail=True)
    def video(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # Implementation to upload a video
```

---

#### Edit

To create a bulk `DELETE` of users endpoint, I would create a Mixin class, as there is no django mixin for Deleting on the index of a router..

```py
class BulkDeleteModelMixin:
    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        self.perform_destroy(queryset)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, 
                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def perform_destroy(self, queryset):
        queryset.delete()
```

And inherit from this class in your viewset

*viewsets.py*

```py
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet
from rest_framework.mixins import (CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, ListModelMixin)
from some_app.mixins import BulkDeleteModelMixin

class UserViewSet(CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, 
                  BulkDeleteModelMixin, ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
```

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer! The problem is that DefaultRouter creates path `DELETE users/{id}`, but i need `DELETE users/`, how can i do this?

Comment: You can remove the `DestroyModelMixin` from the `UserViewSet` signature, which should remove the `DELETE user/{id}` endpoint. You can control the available HTTP actions by inheriting and / overriding the methods that come from these Mixins (rest_framework.mixins)

Comment: yes, if i remove `DestroyModelMixin` it removes `DELETE user/{id}`, but now, how can i add `DELETE users/` to the same path as `GET` and `POST`? This is the main problem. Can you add the solution to your answer?

Comment: thanks for your edited answer, but it doesn't work, i just get `"Method \"DELETE\" not allowed."` this mixin doesn't add `DELETE users/` to router automatically

Comment: P.S i dont know how, but i just add method `delete` and it works with router without any mixin extended